# What is the recommended way to move a LUKS Volume Header backup to another computer?

Tags: linux, backup, permissions, luks

I'm running Linux Mint with a full disk encryption (done during installation).

Following this [guide](https://www.lisenet.com/2013/luks-add-keys-backup-and-restore-volume-header/), I've created a backup of the LUKS header with the following command:

> ```
> # cryptsetup luksHeaderBackup <device> --header-backup-file <file>
> ```
>
> Where  is a LUKS volume disk and  is a name of a header
>   backup file to be created.

I'd like to move `file` using a pen drive to another machine (running Windows) for safekeeping.

Note that `file` file is owned by root, belongs to the root group and only root can read it.

If I do `sudo cp -a`, then I get this error:

> cp: failed to preserve ownership for
>   `<pen drive path>/<file>`: Operation not
>   permitted

Is there a workaround for this? I've thought of changing the ownership of the file from root to myself but I am not sure how this will impact restoring the LUKS header later on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ownership of the file will not impact the LUKS header backup.

About the `failed to preserve ownership` error: your pendrive is most probably formatted with FAT which [does not support ownership](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23520744/2142030).

But you should definitely test your backup by restoring LUKS header with an backup of your disk image.